# How reset date range for Linked Picker on eonasdan Bootstrap 3 Datepicker?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I'm use eonasdan Bootstrap 3 Datepicker for date input.
I want to make a button to reset date range for linked pickers, like in this link:
http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/#linked-pickers

I tried this but it didn't work, minDate and maxDate don't reset.

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
                    $(function () {
                        $('#datetimepicker6').datetimepicker({ format: 'YYYY-MM-DD 00:00:00',locale: 'en-gb',showClear:true });
                        $('#datetimepicker7').datetimepicker({ format: 'YYYY-MM-DD 23:59:59',locale: 'en-gb',showClear:true});
                       
                        
                        $("#datetimepicker6").on("dp.change",function (e) {
                            $('#datetimepicker7').data("DateTimePicker").minDate(e.date);
                        });
                        $("#datetimepicker7").on("dp.change",function (e) {
                            $('#datetimepicker6').data("DateTimePicker").maxDate(e.date);
                        });
                        
                         $('#clearDate').click(function() {
                                 $('#EventDateStart').val('');
                                $('#EventDateEnd').val('');
                                
                                $('#datetimepicker6').data("DateTimePicker").minDate(false);
                                $('#datetimepicker7').data("DateTimePicker").maxDate(false);
                                return false;
                          });
                    });
                </script>
```

Answer (score 4):

Yes, i found solution, i do that :

```js
$('#clearDate').click(function() {
  $('#EventDateStart').val('');
  $('#EventDateEnd').val('');

  $('#datetimepicker6').data("DateTimePicker").minDate(false);
  $('#datetimepicker6').data("DateTimePicker").maxDate(false);
  $('#datetimepicker7').data("DateTimePicker").minDate(false);
  $('#datetimepicker7').data("DateTimePicker").maxDate(false);
  return false;
});
```

Comment: To reset the value with v4 you should use `$('#EventDateStart').data().DateTimePicker.date(null);` as per [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker/issues/669)

Answer (score 0):

Much easier to do like this.

```
        $("#datetimepicker6").on("dp.change", function (e) {
    $('#datetimepicker7').data("DateTimePicker").minDate(e.date);
});
$("#datetimepicker7").on("dp.change", function (e) {
    $('#datetimepicker6').data("DateTimePicker").maxDate(e.date);
});
```